# Remove Input char when not match on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Why this condition is not working?
>
> User can input only '0' and '1' otherwise it should be not entered.

```
<body> 
    <input id="whichkey" />
    <script>
      $( "#whichkey" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        var x = event.which;   
        if(x !== '0' || x !== '1'){
            var userAns = $("#whichkey").val(),     
            shortString = userAns.substr(0,(userAns.length -1));
            $('#whichkey').val(shortString);
        }
      });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: is this a demo?i dont see a question or problem either?thank you for the demo mate.. :)

Comment: `if(x != '0' || x != '1'){` is this intentionally added or not?

Comment: @ Developer107, this condition will delete when not match.

Comment: @AmitKushawaha, your condition doesn't work because the value of 0 & 1 keys aren't 0, 1. Each key on the keyboard has its own value or code it's called `keycodes`. Look at this table: http://www.alt-codes.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
$( "#whichkey" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
    var x = event.which;  
    console.log(x)
    if(x !== 48 && x !== 49 && x !== 96 && x !== 97){
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1u13oLq/)

Comment: This answer is not fully correct as its accepting "!" & ")" symbols as input. Please update your code..

Comment: @Xzandro, What will be the condition for number 0 to 7?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex to replace everything that isn't a 0 or a 1

```
<body> 
    <input id="whichkey" />
    <script>
      $( "#whichkey" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^01]/g, ''));
        }
      });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that !?

```
<body> 
    <input id="whichkey" />
    <script>
      $( "#whichkey" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        var x = event.which;   
        if(x !== 48 && x !== 49 && x !== 96 && x !== 97) $('#whichkey').val(null);
      });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
 <input id="whichkey" onKeyDown="test(event,this.id)"/> 
  press enter key after inputting string
<script>
function test(e,id)
{
    if(e.keyCode==13 || e==13)
    {
         var userAns = $('#'+id).val();
         var shortString =userAns.substr(0,1)
        if(shortString==1 || shortString==0)
        {
            $('#whichkey').val(shortString);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Only 0 & 1 is allowed");
            $('#whichkey').val("");

        }
    }

}

</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<input id="whichkey"/> press enter key after inputting string
  <script>
$("#whichkey").on("keydown",function(e){test(e,this.id)});
function test(e,id)
{ 
    if(e.keyCode==13){
         var userAns = $('#'+id).val();
         var shortString=userAns.substr(0,1);
         (shortString==1)? shortString:shortString="";
            $('#whichkey').val(shortString);
        }
     }

  </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: is that enough for you??